# grant permission

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [grant permission](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30596/grant-permission)

this one is copied from stackoverflow [( original post )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842422/grant-permission), because of advice from [Josien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249353/josien)

i've got a database-role, -login and user

```
CREATE LOGIN dummyLogIn WITH PASSWORD = 'dummyPassword', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
CREATE USER dummyUser FOR LOGIN dummyLogIn;
CREATE ROLE "dummyRole";
```

with user related to the role:

```
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember N'dummyRole', N'dummyUser';
```

everything fine to this point.

now i grant select WITH GRANT OPTION to the group for a specified table:

```
GRANT SELECT ON "dbo"."mytable" TO dummyRole WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

still everythings ok. if i lookup preferences of role in ssms, i see "dummyUser" is a member of this role and the role hast SELECT permission on myTable, including the permission to grant select ( both checkboxes are tagged in preferences-window )

if i try to grant select permission to another group, which is definetely existing i get an errormessage ( no 15151 ): **search for object "myTable" not possible, because object doesn't exist oder neccessary permissions don't exist**. ( errormessage was in german ;) ).

i can easily do a select on the mentioned table - so i assume, the object **DOES** exist.
and i should be able to grant select permission to another group, in my opinion.

**@appended:**

query which throws the error:

**`GRANT SELECT ON "dbo"."mytable" TO childDummyRole` ( logged in as user *dummyUser* )**

childDummyRole and referring objects have been created in the same way as the above mentioned objects:

```
CREATE LOGIN childDummyLogIn WITH PASSWORD = 'childDummyPassword', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
CREATE USER childDummyUser FOR LOGIN childDummyLogIn;
CREATE ROLE "childDummyRole";
```

with user related to the role:

```
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember N'childDummyRole', N'childDummyUser';
```