# grant permission

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've got a database-role, -login and user

```
CREATE LOGIN dummyLogIn WITH PASSWORD = 'dummyPassword', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
CREATE USER dummyUser FOR LOGIN dummyLogIn;
CREATE ROLE "dummyRole";
```

with user related to the role:

```
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember N'dummyRole', N'dummyUser';
```

everything fine to this point.

now i grant select WITH GRANT OPTION to the group for a specified table:

```
GRANT SELECT ON "dbo"."mytable" TO dummyRole WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

still everything is OK. if i lookup preferences of role in ssms, i see "dummyUser" is a member of this role and the role hast SELECT permission on myTable, including the permission to grant select ( both checkboxes are tagged in preferences-window )

if i try to grant select permission to another group, which is definitely existing i get an errormessage ( no 15151 ): **search for object "myTable" not possible, because object doesn't exist or necessary permissions don't exist**. ( errormessage was in German ;) ).

I can easily do a select on the mentioned table - so i assume, the object **DOES** exist.
and i should be able to grant select permission to another group, in my opinion.

**@appended:**

query which throws the error:

**`GRANT SELECT ON "dbo"."mytable" TO childDummyRole` ( logged in as user *dummyUser* )**

childDummyRole and referring objects have been created in the same way as the above mentioned objects:

```
CREATE LOGIN childDummyLogIn WITH PASSWORD = 'childDummyPassword', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
CREATE USER childDummyUser FOR LOGIN childDummyLogIn;
CREATE ROLE "childDummyRole";
```

with user related to the role:

```
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember N'childDummyRole', N'childDummyUser';
```

Comment: You only showed us the SQL commands and setup for the parts that work.  Now you need to show us the same things for the user, groups and commands that do not work.

Comment: Are you trying to grant permissions on myTable as user dummyRole? Not enough information in the question as it is now to help you further...

Comment: information appended in original posting. i thought, the problem is described in the bold textpart.

Comment: Hi Nico, I've merged the identical question you posted here on dba.se with this one migrated in from SO. If you ask any other questions on SO that you decide you want here instead, please flag them on SO for migration rather than cross-posting as that is considerably easier for us to manage!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving that error message because `dummyUser` does not have the proper permissions. In order for that account to grant permission to another user you will have to grant the `dummyUser` security permissions.

You can review the documentation for `GRANT` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to find out what exact permission is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I've overread the fact that you have to use the `AS` clause. Thought `WITH GRANT OPTION` would be sufficient. I'll test it after holiday and remember accepting your answer if things are fine!